# azure data factory - Copy data activity mapping "hh:mm" to SQL "Time" column

Tags: azure-data-factory, timespan

I am trying to ingest a CSV file into Azure SQL with a column with data type of time. The value in the csv file is in this format "hh:mm". I have setup my conversion setting into these settings:
[image: Type Conversion Settings]

But then I am having this error:

ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '23:55' for column name 'systime' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'TimeSpan' (precision:255, scale:7). Additional info: Input string was not in a correct format.

[image: ADF Error]

Not sure how to solve this issue. Can someone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: TIMESPAN is not the same as a time.  Azure SQL doesn't offer time as a data type.  You'll need to use DATETIME OR DATETIME2 and you'll need a date in addition to the time to use that.  Alternatively you can always store the data as string and update your queries to convert it to a date time.  It really depends on what you are trying to achieve as an end result.

Comment: Error message in the sentence and error message in the screenshot are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave the `Timespan` format as `hh\:mm` and tried to debug the pipeline that has the copy activity to copy data from csv file to SQL database.

**Mapping settings:**
[image]

- Received the same error as in the question's image.

> "message": "ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '24:00' for column name 'Datecolumn1' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'TimeSpan' (precision:255, scale:7). Additional info: The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric components is out of range or contains too many digits."

[image]

This is because one of the time data in source csv is `24:00`.
**hh** which represents the hour in the timespan and its value ranges from 0 to 23 only. To resolve this issue, you can modify the source data to remove any values that are out of range for the hour component of the Time data type. In this case, you can remove any values that are equal to or greater than 24. You can also use mapping dataflow in ADF to replace '24:00' with '00:00'.

Steps to do in dataflow:

- Take the source csv dataset in source transformation
- Then take the derived column transformation and give the expression as `iif(valuation_time == '24:00', '00:00', valuation_time )`
  [image]
- Take the sink transformation with SQL dataset.

Comment: Thanks Aswin. Removing the values that are equal to or greater than 24 did not solve my issue. It was still showing that error after modification. The only way to solve this was your suggestion of using dataflow.